# Old Asp.Net Web Site Project - No Project file?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5

So I have an Asp.Net website that i'm responsible for.  I'm having a build issue, that as far as I can tell, may be either MacAfee or some other random cause.

But thinking back, I want to say the problem started when I added a "Test.aspx" form to the site, did some testing, then removed the Test.aspx form from the site.

I'm using TFS 2010 as my source control as well.  Which I don't know if it applies or not.

My question is, is there some hidden location where all files to be included in publishing a website is maintained?

Is there a Project file for a Web Site app and if so where is it?

I've built the site using MSBUILD and notice some metaprj project file in the output but I can't seem to find any such file.

Comment: If it's a web site then there is no project file. It's just whatever happens to be in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Web Site apps aren't meant to be built into a dll file.  There is a conversion wizard to make it a web project but it doesn't always work well.  My advice would be to continue to work with it as a Web Site app.  The code files are compiled at at runtime on first use.  You can run from Visual Studio or setup a site in IIS.  Nothing is hidden in a Web Site app and there is no project file.  So, you shouldn't have a build issue because you shouldn't be building.  Try to run the app as is and if you get an error let us know what the specific message is.