# How to generate .csproj file in Visual Studio 2019 for ASP.NET project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I received a legacy solution but I can't find the `.csproj` file. Is there any way to recreate this file?

Comment: Do you have the .SLN file?

Comment: dup? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639944/old-asp-net-web-site-project-no-project-file